# Finding the origin of a string in an object file created by gcc

Tags: c

I have a third party source code which prints a string to a log file. I am unable to find where the string is being printed from. I cannot find in the source file. However, when I grep, it tells me that one of the object files is matching. I cannot find it in the corresponding C file. How can an object file contain a string which is not in the source files. (.h or .C)

Comment: It could be generated in a preprocessor macro or split over multiple lines. Try grepping for parts of the string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
for i in object1.o object2.o object3.o; do echo $i; strings |grep "thing to find"; done
```